# Why does Paypal send an 'subscr_eot' IPN instantly and not after t3 when subscription payment is set to non-recurring

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to offer a limited time, non-renewable membership option to my users. So I thought that using Paypal subscriptions and setting it to non-recurring (src=0) would work fine and my server would receive an IPN after "x" days if I set p3="X" and t3="D".

So for example, if I want to offer a 30 day membership option(non-renewable), I would build the paypal button with:

```
src="0"
p3="30"
t3="D"
```

then after 30 days from the 'subscr_signup' IPN, I would receive a 'subscr_eot' IPN and then I could terminate the membership.

But that's not what happens in my tests in sandbox. I'm receiving the 'subscr_eot' IPN as soon as the users signs up, right after 'subscr_signup'. Even worse, sometimes I get the 'subscr_eot' IPN before 'subscr_signup'! Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I use a BuyItNow button for this case.

Comment: Basically, if you set it to be non-recurring, the period you specify is irrelevant. You're not telling PayPal how long you're providing services: you're telling it how often to bill. If it's only billing once, then as far as PayPal is concerned, it's done after the first time.